# Mapping 16 bit grayscale to 8 bit in PNG

Tags: c#, png

I'm trying to decode a PNG in C# with 16 bits per channel (bpc) for a grayscale image. I believe I'm decoding the correct raw values however when I convert to 8bpc for returning values I'm not calculating the same values as `System.Drawing`, Gimp or `SixLabors.ImageSharp`.

Given the following byte values of a single grayscale pixel:

```
byte b0 = data[index];
byte b1 = data[index + 1];
```

I've tried the following mappings:

```
byte result = b0;
byte result = (byte)(255 * (((b0 << 8) + b1)/ushort.MaxValue));
byte result = (byte)(((b0 << 8) + b1)/256.0);
```

But none of these approaches seem to match the values from other software predicted for the following values:

```
b0   b1   expected
55   186  55
67   135  67
35   241  36
```

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding the correct method for normalizing back to an 8 bpc value.

The image in question is this:

[image: A 16 by 16 pixel Grayscale image with 16 bpc]

Comment: This is a good question but you should add whether you use Forms or WPF and how you decode the PNG, there might be some infrastructure you can leverage instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: From what I can see you are dividing by `ushort.MaxValue` before multiplying by `255`, which throws away the low order bits you will want later since the division will be integral. Multiply by `255` first in the first mapping.

Comment: @Aybe this is actually just vanilla C#, I'm trying to write a PNG decoder just to see how it's done so I wanted to see how the wheel gets built. The decoding logic I currently have is here: https://github.com/EliotJones/BigGustave/blob/master/src/BigGustave/Decoder.cs

Comment: @NetMage thanks, I tried it this way as well, it works for most of the cases but it looks like the (55, 186) case still fails but I checked this in Gimp and ImageSharp and both of those treat the value as 56 so it looks like GDI+ from System.Drawing does something weird with its rounding of values when mapping back.

Comment: Your post doesn't make clear what is wrong in that case - you show expected, but not the incorrect value you get from `result`? Or `result` 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's the official method to convert a bit depth:**

https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#13Sample-depth-rescaling

```
output = floor((input * MAXOUTSAMPLE / MAXINSAMPLE) + 0.5)

where

MAXINSAMPLE = (2^sampledepth)-1
MAXOUTSAMPLE = (2^desired_sampledepth)-1
```

So if I take your last example:

```
35 << 8 | 241 == 8960 | 241 == 9201
9201 * 255 / 65535 == 2346255 / 65535 == 35
floor(35 + 0.5) == 35
```

**Why not `36` ?**

[There might gamma being involved](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#13Decoder-gamma-handling).

**Conclusion:**

Check first if your in-house implementation correctly follows the specifications then adjust accordingly.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/